# Is every metric space a subspace of some connected metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Is every metric space a subspace of some connected metric space? If the space itself is connected then we're done, but if not then I think we can extend our metric space to make it connected.  I'm not sure whether this will work or not, but intuitively I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @Ilya: This space need not be connected, right? The union of two open balls with disjoint closures is dense in the union of their closures, but the union of their closures isn't connected.

Comment: How about add a point $p$ at distance $1$ from every other point, and then run a line from $p$ to every connected component?

Comment: @Neal I think that's the right idea, but your specific construction will violate the triangle inequality if there are points of distance $> 2$.

Comment: @MartianInvader True. It occurs to me that it will be even easier to take the metric cone on $X$.

Answer (score 10):

If we just want $(X,d)$ to be any subspace of a larger connected space, then sure: we don't even need metric then, just Tychonoff: every Tychonoff space embeds into a (connected) space $[0,1]^I$ for some set $I$.

If we want $X$ to be dense in the larger connected space $Y$, then $Y$ is called a connectification. In that case there are examples of metric spaces without a metric connectification (see the encyclopedia of general topology, chapter on connectifications), for references and some positive results as well.

Comment: no in general, see 
http://books.google.com/books?id=JWyoCRkLFAkC&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=metric+connectification&source=bl&ots=iihbm_lS5g&sig=P57TCyTc1HOFjLgQwm_zYgX3s8I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cDh2VJaJBYahNpKigNgN&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=metric%20connectification&f=false 
and 
http://www.auburn.edu/~gruengf/papers/connect.pdf
In general, google metric connectification

Comment: It is always possible, however, to embed a metric space in a connected metric space, albeit not necessarily as a dense subset: every metric space $X$ embeds in $J(w(X))^\omega$, where $J(\kappa)$ is the metric hedgehog with $\kappa$ spines.

Comment: What is $w(X)$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff the minimal size of a base of $X$. It's called the weight of $X$ and for metric spaces it's the same as the minimal size of a dense set, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks.

Comment: Wow ... I've lived this long and never met a metric hedgehog. Cool, @BrianM.Scott! :)

Comment: I suspect the question was asking if every metric space isometrically embeds into a connected metric space, though the wording is confusing.

Answer (score 8):

In fact every metric space admits a canonical isometric embedding into a contractible metric space, as follows. If $X$ is a metric space, let $\hat{X}$ denote the space of weak contractions $X \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, where a *weak contraction* $X \to Y$ between two metric spaces is a map $f : X \to Y$ such that $d_Y(f(x_0), f(x_1)) \le d_X(x_0, x_1)$. This space is a metric space when equipped with the sup norm

$$d_{\hat{X}}(f, g) = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x) - g(x)|.$$

There is a canonical embedding

$$X \ni x \mapsto (y \mapsto d(x, y)) \in \hat{X}$$

which one can straightforwardly verify is an isometry. This is a slight variant of the [Yoneda embedding](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding) for metric spaces regarded as [enriched categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#lawvere_metric_spaces).

Answer (score 2):

Use Kuratowski embedding to embed your metric space isometrically into a Banach space.

Comment: Fix $x_0 \in (X,d)$. Then map $x \in X$ to $f_x: X \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f_x(y)=d(x,y)-d(x_0,y)$, and note that $f_x \in C^\ast(X)$ the Banach space of bounded continuous functions on $X$ (in the sup-norm). This defines the Kuratowski isometric embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to embed any metric space $X$ in a connected metric space.  For each pair of distinct points $x,y\in X$, adjoin to $X$ a path from $x$ to $y$, and extend the metric to points on the path by making the path have length $d(x,y)$ (so distances are defined by taking the least distance which can be achieved along the paths or through $X$; by making the paths have length $d(x,y)$, distances between points of $X$ will be unchanged).  The result will be a metric space in which $X$ embeds isometrically which is connected (in fact, path-connected).