# Examples of disconnected metric spaces that cannot be isometrically embedded into a connected metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

> Please give me examples of disconnected metric spaces that cannot be isometrically embedded into connected metric spaces.

I have just started to study connected metric spaces and I haven't found out a metric space $X$ which isn't a subspace from another metric space such that $X$ isn't connected.

Every counterexample that I've looked, has been subspaces from a bigger metric space, e.g. $[0, 1]\cup[2, 3]$ which fails to be an interval in $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|$).

It might be topological space that isn't connected but for metric spaces? is there any apart from discrete metric spaces?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should modify your title, saying something like "Examples of disconnected metric spaces that cannot be embedded into connected metric spaces" or similar.  The current title is a bit misleading.

Comment: FYI, not even discrete metric spaces (regardless of their cardinalities) are examples you seek.  Maybe such examples do not exist at all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1040622/707239

Comment: See the Kuratowski embedding defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1043655/4280).

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is any bounded metric space then $C(X)$, the space of real continuous functions on $X$ is  a connected metric space under the sup norm and the map $x \to f_x$, where $f_x(y)=d(x,y)$, is an **isometric** embedding of $X$ into $C(X)$. Hence the example you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right, thank you.